# Remove index,index.php error handle with trailing slash PHP Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with my Htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L,QSA]
```

My Directory Structure is:

**Public_Html**

```
  css/style.css
   img/icon.png
   /2/user.php
  index.php
  create.php
```

Now the above htaccess code is removing the .php extension from the URL.

Examples

```
 -> example.com/index.php -> example.com/index
 -> example.com/2/user.php -> example.com/2/user
```

**Problems with this Htaccess File**

1. I want to hide the index too
   Example: example.com/index -> example.com
2. If user types example.com/index.php then he should be redirected to example.com
3. If user type things which do not exist then it should point to example.com

   **Example:** `example.com///*/// -> example.com`
4. When it removes the .php extension then a trailing slash should be added to the end.

**Example:** `example.com/create.php -> example.com/create/`

5. If a user wants to access create.php and enter `/create without /` at the end then it should be automatically added.

   **Example:** `example.com/create -> example.com/create/`

In other words, if after removing .php these both works as same

```
**Example:** example.com/create = example.com/create/
```

6. But user should still be able to access the directory

   **Example:** `example.com/2 -> example.com/2/`

   Here 2 is a folder.

I have some problem with this htaccess script. I searched a lot on Google and Stack Overflow but still can't find any solution.

*This is not a duplicate question. Please check it carefully before marking it as a duplicate. I would be glad if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here is everything you need, all questions are answered with code, information, and examples! Providing 1 by 1 step for what each does and then the whole code!

---

**1-) Resolving .php extension**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

`example.com/user.php` will be working if you go to `example.com/user`

---

2-) **Redirecting wrong links that don't exist to example.com**

If a user types a link which doesn't exist, for example, `example.com///*`, the user will be automatically redirected to `example.com`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

3-) **Redirect** `example.com/index.php` **or** `example.com/index` **to** `example.com`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(?:\.php)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

---

**4-) Remove trailing slash if it is not a directory else add**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have a trailing slash added after a normal file, this will remove it. If it is a directory and has, it will remain. If it doesn't have, a trailing slash will be automatically added to it.

You will be able to access directories!

---

**5-) Removing .php from URL ( Redirect to file name without .php )**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(php|cfm)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(cfm|php)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

---

**The whole code together for .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(?:\.php)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(php|cfm)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(cfm|php)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

I hope this has helped you.

Happy to help, enjoy!

Comment: Its good code but its not completely working according to question problem. 1. when i open example.com/2/ it should show the contents of folder named one but its showing home. 2. when i open example.com/index then it should hide index. If these can be problems are solved then the code is awesome. Thanks for reply and edit. Please if help me with these problems.

Comment: @Kim Check the new code, read it carefully and test it before asking!
I have edited the whole answer with ALL of your questions and requirements. Spent a lot of time to put it all together. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Its working but just little problem when someone type www.example.com/create.php then its not hiding the .php . For example- www.example.com/create.php - > www.example.com/create.php instead of this it should do this www.example.com/create.php -> www.example.com/create .              This code will be better if you just solve this last query. Thanks for helping me. BTW i created account on your site. Please fix this if you can.

Comment: @Kim I edited my answer again for you, now if they load example.com/user it will work, and if they go to example.com/user.php they will be redirected to example.com/user

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked correctly. I signed up on your website please check my email their and msg me if possible.